# How to OnInitDialog every CPropertyPage in MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc

I have 2 `CPropertyPage` objects; right now, the second page will only hit `OnInitDialog` if I click on the second page.

How can I initialize it right away when program starts?

Comment: properties.AddPage(&m_page1);
properties.AddPage(&m_page2);

Comment: properties.SetActivePage() you have to do as well

Comment: mySheet.AddPage(&page1);
 mySheet.AddPage(&page2);
 mySheet.SetActivePage(&page1);
 mySheet.SetActivePage(&page2);
Hi i did this, but right now page2 is initialized and not page 1. Page1 only initialize when i click on it. thanks.

Comment: its local method so deleted answer

Comment: It do set => SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR) ProCheckProc);

Comment: what is hWnd and procheckproc? do i need to create a variable for it ? thanks .

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Initializing resources when they are needed is an extremely common pattern (so common in fact, that we often don't even think about it, e.g. when defining a local variable). What's the reason for your application to violate this pattern?

Comment: @IInspectable for example, you use your controls on different pages to store data, and want to initialize them, which is not possible without creating them.

Comment: My two cents on this: the question is *why* activity/availability of a non-default page would be relevant at this early time. Perhaps this is a matter of improper layer separation - perhaps operation state should be kept in a plain non-GUI document / data model type (aggregated by sheet? Perhaps with std::shared_ptr?) rather than in an awfully GUI-dependency-infested type, and then the relevant GUI page would consult or/and update the (already tweaked) operation state *when* it starts to get activated...

Answer (score 4):

You can add `PSP_PREMATURE` to the `dwFlags` field of each property page's `m_psp` data member (a `PROPSHEETPAGE` structure). This forces the *actual creation* of that page (thus calling its `OnInitDialog()` function) when the parent property sheet is created, rather than waiting until the page is selected.

The only [online documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/aa453562(v=msdn.10)) I can find for this is now 'deprecated', but the technique *does* still work.

> - dwFlags
>    ...
>    `PSP_PREMATURE` The page is created when the property sheet is created. Usually, the page is not created until the
>   first time it is selected.

You can add this flag in the constructor for each page; something like this:

```cpp
class MyPropPage : public CPropertyPage
{
public:
    MyPropPage(UINT idd) : CPropertyPage(idd) {
        m_psp.dwFlags |= PSP_PREMATURE; // Add the 'premature' flag on construction
        //...
    }
//...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a `WM_TIMER` message in your `CPropertySheet` like this:

```
BOOL CMyPropertySheet::OnInitDialog() 
{   
    SetTimer(1, 1, NULL);

    return CPropertySheet::OnInitDialog();
}

void CMyPropertySheet::OnTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEvent) 
{
    if (nIDEvent == 1)
    {
        KillTimer(1);
        SetActivePage(1);  // initialize second tab
        SetTimer(2, 1, NULL);
    }
    else if (nIDEvent == 2)
    {
        KillTimer(2);
        SetActivePage(0);  // back to first tab
        
        // to hide the initialization process, you might want to create
        // CMyPropertySheet with the WS_VISIBLE style disabled and wait
        // until all pages are initialized:
        ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);            
    }

    CPropertySheet::OnTimer(nIDEvent);
}
```